# Magento 2.3.2 not reflecting changes for phtml from Magento 2.4.4

Tags: php, magento2

My test Server which has Magento 2.3.2 is not reflecting changes for phtml from my local server Magento 2.4.4.

I edit my files locally and then upload them to a test server that has 2.3.2 but it doesn't show changes to what I have on my local 2.4.4. It's just the footer links.

Template path and name:

> \app\design\frontend<mytheme><mytheme>\Magento_Theme\templates\html\footer\links.phtml

It is working fine on 2.4.4 so I'm wondering if it works differently on 2.3.2?

I already clean cached and all of these commands:

```
sudo bin/magento cache:clean

sudo bin/magento cache:flush

sudo bin/magento indexer:reindex

sudo bin/magento setup:upgrade

sudo bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

I also just realized that some of the things I did are not compatible with 2.3.2

Comment: Tried clean cache on test server?

Comment: I did, I'll edit

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that some of the things I did is not compatible with 2.3.2. So one of the reasons why it wasn't showing up. After fixing these changes started to appear. I hope this helps someone else too who's working on different versions.